# How to reload a part of model with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

How can I "reload" a part of viewmodel with jquery, without `POST` rest of form?

Firstly, code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @ViewBag.Status

    <div id="haveToReload">
    @foreach (var type in OrderTools.getDeliveryTypes(int valueFromDropDownList))
    {
        <div style="width:400px; ">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.SelectedDeliveryTypeID, type.DeliveryTypeID, new { name = "DeliveryType", id = type.DeliveryTypeID })
            <label for="@type.DeliveryTypeID">@type.Name | @type.Price | @type.RealisationDays </label>
        </div>
    }
    </div>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CountryID)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m=> m.CountryID, UserTools.getCountries(),  new { @class="dropdownlist" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CountryID)

    (...)
}
```

My idea is that- if user change value from `DropDownListFor`, it will automaticly "reload" `<div id="haveToReload">..</div>` with new value for `OrderTools.getDeliveryTypes(int valueFromDropDownList)`, and show deliveryTypes for specyfic country.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the steps below:

1. Make an ajax call on change on dropdown which will fetch the data.
2. Then on success of ajax call you can replace your view with the new data.

Ajax Call :

```
$("#dropDownId").change() {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "Controller/Action",
          data: { 'dropDownValue' : "+ $(this).val() +"} ,
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (result) {
              $("#haveToReload").replaceWith(result); // your replacing logic
    },
    error: function () {
    }
});
}
```